# Proving $z''_u+z''_v=(x^2+y^2)(z''_x+z''_y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> If $x=e^u\cos(v)$, $y=e^u\sin(v)$, $z=f(x,y)$, prove that
>   $$z''_u+z''_v=(x^2+y^2)(z''_x+z''_y).$$

It seems simple at first sight, but it's too much answering, so I think I did not notice the point.

So any idea?

Comment: When $z=f(x)$, the expression $z'$ usually means "derivative of z with respect to x", but in this case it is not clear whether the differentiation should be with respect to x or y. The meaning of $z''$ is not clear.

Comment: "I think I did not notice the point." I think so, too. And without an explanation of the objects nobody will be able to help you. Sorry.

Comment: I think the intended meaning of $z''u$ is $\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2}$, and similarly for the others.  This does, at least, produce a correct equation.

Comment: I edited the question according to @FredH suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fairly straightforward exercise in multivariable chain rule, and that is likely the intended solution.

A non-intended solution is to declare $Z=x+iy$ and $W=u+iv$, so that $Z=g(W)=e^{W}$ and using [Wirthinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives), and [complex Laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2177411/2633) we get for holomorphic $g$:

$$\Delta_W f(g(W)) = \left|\frac{\partial }{\partial W}g\right|^2 \Delta_Z f(Z)$$

which in this case gives $z''_u+z''_v=|e^W|^2(z''_x+z''_y)=(x^2+y^2)(z''_x+z''_y)$ as wanted.