# Complex Functions and the Laplacian

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking at the following two problems from Stein and Shakarchi's "Complex Analysis" textbook:[image]

There are a number of similar questions here, but many of them (like the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177365/whats-the-laplace-operator-in-a-complex-plane-z-xiy)) seem to take for granted that we may not have equality of mixed partials.  In 10 there is no assumption that f is holomorphic, so why would the operators in 10 commute?  If I directly apply the operators in 10 to $u+iv$ I get
$$
\begin{align*}
4\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}[u+iv] ={}& u_{xx}+u_{yy}+v_{yx}-v_{xy} + i(v_{xx}+v_{yy}-u_{yx}+u_{xy}),\\
4\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}[u+iv] ={}& u_{xx}+u_{yy}-v_{yx}+v_{xy} + i(v_{xx}+v_{yy}+u_{yx}-u_{xy}).
\end{align*}
$$
So it seems peculiar to me, and from other documents I've read I get the impression there's an assumption that I'm not making.  For 11, the answer is clearly true since if $f$ is holomorphic then it is analytic.  My question is if there is some elegant manner to get around this, or if perhaps I should just assume that $u$ and $v$ are $C^2$ functions?

Comment: The functions on which the Laplacian operates have to be at least $C^2$. A sufficient condition for equality of mixed partial derivatives is that both mixed partials are continuous.

Comment: Yes, thank you Mark.  I figured I should assume they are $C^2$ but couldn't come up with why.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is correct! The only piece you miss is that for $C^2$ real functions on the plane the 2nd order derivatives commute. [Symmetry_of_second_derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) (the condition of Schwarz's theorem is the function has 2nd partial derivatives and they are continuous - which is satistified by the definition of C2 function)

$$
u_{xy}=u_{yx}, v_{xy}=v_{yx}
$$
Then your result could be further simplified into
$$
\begin{align*}
4\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}[u+iv] ={}& u_{xx}+u_{yy} + i(v_{xx}+v_{yy}),\\
4\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}[u+iv] ={}& u_{xx}+u_{yy} + i(v_{xx}+v_{yy}).
\end{align*}
$$
Then you get the desired Laplacian expression.

Comment: Thank you Binxu, I knew it would work if $u$ and $v$ where $C^2$, but wasn't sure why I could assume so.